# Permuting the elements of an array in CUDA

Tags: arrays, cuda, parallel-processing, element, swap

I need to permute the elements of an array (row of a matrix) with parallel programming in CUDA.

My attempt is the following

```
__global__ void CudaProcessingKernel(int *dataA) 
{

    int bx = blockIdx.x;  
    int tx = threadIdx.x;  
    int tid = bx * XTHREADS + tx;  

    if(tid< 16)     // matrix 4x4
    {

        if(tid==4)  dataB[tid]=dataB[5];
        if(tid==5)  dataB[tid]=dataB[6];
        if(tid==6)  dataB[tid]=dataB[7];
        if(tid==7)  dataB[tid]=dataB[4];
    }

    __syncthreads();
}
```

The above approach doesn't work.

What I want:

```
input B[1][]  =  **EC 6E 4C 90** => output **6E 4C 90 EC**
```

My output is:

```
**6E 90 4C 6E**
```

`B[4]` and `B[7]` have same value. I think that, in the case of parallel processing, I should be able to avoid the temporary storage: `int TEMP = B[4]; B[7]=TEMP`.

What is my fault? What kind of memory I have to use?

Comment: You have a race condition. Would you consider using atomic operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using atomic operations to avoid the race condition whose effect you are observing. As atomic operation, you can use `atomicCAS`. The approach below will work for any grid size. As an alternative approach, you can define a new, temporary array (as you mentioned in your post) and avoid atomic operations.

Here is the code using CUDA atomics.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

__global__ void swap_kernel(int* data) {

    int tid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (tid < N) { atomicCAS(&data[tid], data[tid], data[(tid+1) % N]); }

}

void main() {

    int* h_vec = (int*) malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    int* d_vec; cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vec,N*sizeof(int));

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) h_vec[i] = i;

    cudaMemcpy(d_vec,h_vec,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    swap_kernel<<<2,8>>>(d_vec);

    cudaMemcpy(h_vec,d_vec,N*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%i %i\n",i,h_vec[i]);

    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. Although I don't understand how "atomicCAS" work, but your code is very detailed. I have a question : Between using "atomicCAS" and copy value to temporary storage, what is BEST ?

Comment: @user3505155 `atomicCAS` means atomic "compare and swap" and is described in Appendix B.12.1.8. of the CUDA C Programming Guide. Concerning your question, I do not think it is a matter of performance, but of code consistency. Attempting to use temporary storage will give to race conditions and atomic operations is the only way (unless you do not want to re-conceive the code) to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying data in global while other are reading so the output is wrong. You should do something like that. Like you read your data and once every thread has the data registered you write into the new element of your array. Like:

```
[..]
int local = dataB[indexToSwap+tid];

__syncthreads();

dataB[indexSwap+tid] = local;
```

Comment: Take into account that `__syncthreads` ensures visibility of the memory operations only within a block.